# Make template appear with ng-show and display content with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to get a template to have functionality with utilizing ng-show and then getting content to appear with ng-repeat.  I am new to angular and this is my first project.  Here is the factory the template is linked to.

```
(function () {

    function Message($firebaseArray) {
        var Message = {};
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");

        Message.getByRoomId = function (roomId) {
            console.log('Linked.')
            ref.orderByChild('messages').equalTo(roomId);
        }

        return Message;
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .factory('Message', ['$firebaseArray', Message]);

})();
```

Here is the template it is linked too.

```
<div class="room-list" ng-repeat="room in roomController.rooms" ng-click="Message.getRoomById()">
    {{ room.$value }}
</div>

<div class="button-open" ng-controller="ModalCtrl as mod">
    <button type="button" ng-click="mod.open()">Create new room</button>
</div>

<div class="chat-content-true" ng-show="message.Room.getRoomById.length > 0">
    <div class="chat-room" ng-repeat="chat in message.Message.getRoomById()">
        {{ chat.$value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The two things I am struggling with is one, I cannot find a way to link my factory to my template. and two I cannot get the div "chat-room" to appear in the current setup.  I appreciate any pointers for this thanks in advance.

Here is the other controller for Room.

```
(function () {

    function RoomCtrl (Room) {
        this.rooms = Room.all;
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('RoomCtrl', ['Room', RoomCtrl]);

})();
```

and this the factory I have linked to RoomCtrl.

```
(function () {

    function Room ($firebaseArray) {

        var Room = {};
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("rooms");
        var rooms = $firebaseArray(ref);

        Room.all = rooms;

        Room.add = function (room) {
            rooms.$add(room);
        }

        return Room;

    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .factory('Room', ['$firebaseArray', Room]);

})();
```

Comment: can you show the **entire** markup and associated controllers?  right now you are showing `roomController.rooms` (which makes me think that `roomsController` is a controller) but aren't showing where this controller is instantiated.  also, you are showing another section that *might* be part of the `roomController`, but are referencing it simply as `message` (which either implies that `message` is another controller, or `message` is an object of `$scope`, but since you appear to be using Controller as, `$scope` doesn't feel likely).

Comment: I added both my controller and factory for roomController.rooms.  Thanks for your time.